# Search for media files in Object

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way to loop through an object and find all strings with something like

```
 var types = [ ".jpg" , ".png" , ".mp3 ", ".mp4"];
```

The Object contains lots of sub-objects that may or may not have media files in them .

I just want a list of all media files in there?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of your object?

Comment: Can you post here exact object (referencing `The Object contains lots of sub-objects`)? Having only this array, this is not a big deal to do that.

Comment: please add some more information what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties):

you can iterate over all object properties with this snippet:

```
for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
       // iterate here over all types
       // like this:

       var filtered = types.filter(function(type){
                          return property.indexOf(type) > -1 ; // substr 
                     });

       if(filtered.length > -1){
       // found a type

       }
    }
}
```